# Should I use an extra "will" in the subordinate clause?

Tags: subordinate-clauses

please let me know which of these are incorrect (I think the second sentences that are with an extra 'will" are incorrect. What do native speakers really use?

> 1. I will cook whatever my mom cooks.
> 2. I will cook whatever my mom will cook.

> 1. I will read everything that my dad advises me to read.
> 2. I will read everything that my dad will advise me to read.

Comment: the sentences with the second "will" are grammatically correct, but not idiomatic. A native speaker would likely use the first one.

Comment: If you use will in the second clause, it changes the meaning. "I'll do whatever she'll do" is different than: I will do whatever she does". They can be idiomatic, yes.

Comment: @Lambie does your second sentence mean a regular action in the present, like in "He will smoke his cigars every day. I hate him doing that"? Could you clarify on the meaning of both?

Comment: Neither of yours are regular actions. That smoke one yes.

Comment: @Lambie how come the meaning is different? Now that I think of it, it seems like "I'll do whatever she'll do" and "I will do whatever she does" are basically the same meaning-wise, the latter being simplified in terms of tenses so as to eliminate redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

All four sentences are gramatically correct.

It is possible to interpret "my mom cooks" and "my dad advises me to read" as applying to current action. However, I think that those are more likely to refer to future action. In that case, they have the same meaning as "my mom will cook" and "my dad will advise me to read".

If future action is meant, then the sentences labelled "1" would be more common, although you might see the sentences labelled "2" in some circumstances.